# How to convert String to drawable for imageView in android

Tags: android, image, imageview, drawable

I got an imageView in First activity and I want to pass over the string to the 2nd activity in order to display the same image.

I got this code in first activity:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);    
String sharePre = imageView.getDrawable().toString();
```

As a result, I got `String sharePre = android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@42a74470`

Problem: How can I convert the String back to Drawable in 2nd activity, in other word, I want to use

`ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
imageView2.setImageDrawable(sharePre.toDrawrable);`

Comment: How are you setting the image for `imageView` in the first Activity?

Comment: I would rather convert URI of the image to string and send it another activity, where another activity gets image from URI